# Order of cyclic subgroups in symmetric groups

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

What is the largest possible order of a cyclic subgroup of $S_7$?

What's an example of this?

I really just need a better understanding of cyclic subgroups of symmetric groups. I know that the largest possible subgroup of $S_7$ is of size $7$. And I know all the possible cycle structures.
Would it be $6$ because $\left<(1 2 3 4 5 6 )\right>$ is a cyclic subgroup generated by the size of $S_6$ or the element $(1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6)$?

Comment: It's not asking the same thing

Comment: In a way, yes, it is.

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding then

Comment: Might it be that you think that "maximum element order" and "largest size of a cyclic subgroup" are two different things?

Comment: Possibly, yeah.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. The order of a cyclic subgroup is the order of any of its generators.
2. The order of an element of $S_n$ is the lcm of the lengths of the cycles in its disjoint cycle decomposition.

Example: in $S_7$ you have a cyclic subgroup of order $10=2\times 5$ generated by $(1\ 2)(3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)$.

Comment: Does this mean it could be order 12? Because 4 × 3 is generated by (1234)(567)

Comment: @Hopper Yes!${}$

Comment: Thank you then!